# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n$$

- With the Root Test I get: $e\times \frac{1}{e}=1$, which doesn't determine whether it converges or not.
- With the Ratio Test I have to compute:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{{(n+1)}^2}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+1}&=\exp\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-1\right)(2n+1)\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}2+\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\exp2=e^2
\end{align}

$e^2\times \frac{1}{e}=e>1$, so it diverges

Is this correct? Im kinda new to this concept so I need a little help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You limit computations are not exactly correct even though they give the final good answer. However to exactly compute the limit:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^{2n+1} &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n\right)^{2}\left(1+\frac1n\right) = e^2\times 1 = e^2
\end{align}

Comment: But when we have $1^∞$ don't we use $\exp\lim_{n->∞}(a-1)(the power)$? Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: I am not sure of understanding your comment. But are you speaking about $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = e$

Comment: yeah I'm talking about that. For example, the reason $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$ is because $\exp\lim_{n->∞}(1+\frac{1}{n}-1)(n)=\exp\lim_{n->∞}\frac{1}{n}*n=\exp 1=e$

Doesn't this apply to $\lim_{n->∞}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2n+1}$ too?

Comment: No your justification is not quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition for convergence is that the $n^{th}$ term should go to zero. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+1/n)}^{n^2}{(1/e)}^{n}=A.$ Then

$\implies \lim_{n \to \infty}{n^2}\log{(1+1/n)}+{n}\log{1/e}=\log A $

$\implies \lim_{n \to \infty}{n^2}{(1/n-1/{2n^2}+...)}-{n}=\log A  $

$\implies \log A=-1/2$

Contradiction, hence It is divergent. What you have done is also correct apart from what @youem mentioned.

Comment: Oh that works too. Thanks! Could you tell me why the $\exp$ part is incorrect? Afaik, when we have $1^∞$ we can use that method

Comment: Yeah, your method works for this special case because if you expand the log you get the same thing. Try to compute (a^(1/n))^n with this method it would be hard. But the limit is a. I would suggest taking a log to do this kind of calculation.

Comment: I mean...$(a^{\frac{1}{n}})^n$, you would just cancel out the power. But yeah I do get what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either of these tests, because a necessary condition for convergence is that the general term tends to $0$.

Now, using Taylor-Young's expansion, we have
\begin{align}
\biggl(1+\frac1n\biggr)^{n^2}&=\mathrm e^{n^2\log\bigl(1+\frac1n\bigr)}=\mathrm e^{n^2\log\bigl(1+\frac1n\bigr)}\\
&=\mathrm e^{n^2\bigl(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+o\bigl(\frac 1{n^2}\bigr)\bigr)}=\mathrm e^{n-\frac1{2}+o\bigl(1\bigr)}
\end{align}
so that $$\biggl(1+\frac1n\biggr)^{n^2}\frac1{\mathrm e^n}= \mathrm e^{-\frac1{2}+o\bigl(1\bigr)},$$
which tends to $\dfrac1{\sqrt{\mathrm e}}$.

Comment: oh, I understand your method too, thanks to symbolab lol. But yeah I have to do it using the convergence tests, cuz last time I didn't and got points marked off. Thanks anyway

Comment: But perhaps, last time the context was different. This explanation (the general term does not tend to $0$) is sometimes formulated as ‘the series diverges trivially’. The toot and ratio tests, normally, are  used in the case when the general term does tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, using that $\log (1+x)\ge x-\frac {x^2}2$ we obtain

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}=e^{n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\ge e^{n-\frac12}=\frac{e^n}{\sqrt e}$$

and therefore

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n\ge \frac{e^n}{\sqrt e}\cdot \frac1{e^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt e}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Mean value theorem and inequality proving](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993505/505767)